# missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've checked the other answers to similar questions - but so far no luck.

I have the following code:

```
$("#alphaindex").click(function(e) {      
                var item = $(this).attr("title");
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $.getJSON("getContacts.cfc?method=getContacts&returnformat=json",{"alpha":item}, function(res,code){
                    if(res.ROWCOUNT > 0){
                        for(var i=0; i<res.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
                            s += "<h3 class='postTitle'>" + res.DATA.CONTACTFIRSTNAME[i] res.DATA.CONTACTLASTNAME[i] + "</h3>"
                            + "<p class='postDesc'>" + res.DATA.CONTACTEMAIL[i] + "</p>"
                            + "<p class='postDesc'>" + res.DATA.CONTACTMOBILE[i] + "</p> <br class='clr' />"
                            };
                        s += "";
                        } 
                    else {
                        var s = "Sorry, nothing matched your search.";
                    }
                    $("#results").html(s);

                    },"json");
                })
            });
```

and I'm getting the ; missing before statement message in relation to the line:

```
s += "<h3 class='postTitle'>...res.DATA.CONTACTLASTNAME[i] + "</h3>"
```

according to firebug.

I'm sure it's something obvious - hopefully your eyes will spot it where mine have failed!

Comment: Try moving the `+` signs up a line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you missing a `+` sign between these two in that line?

```
res.DATA.CONTACTFIRSTNAME[i] res.DATA.CONTACTLASTNAME[i]
```